# Spring security configuration in spring boot not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I am using spring security with spring boot. But my spring security configuration is now working as expected.

**Note** : H2 database is running as a separate database in server mode ( *Not in embedded mode* ).

Here are my project details :

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Application.properties**

```
server.port=8085

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**EmployeeeResource.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
@Slf4j
public class EmployeeResource {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/greetEmployee", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Employee !!!";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/getAllEmployees", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployee() {
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/getEmployee/{employeeId}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable("employeeId") int employeeId) {
        Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeId(employeeId);
        if (optionalEmployee.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(optionalEmployee.get(), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/createEmployee", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Random random = new Random();
        employee.setEmployeeId(random.nextInt(9999));
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        log.info("Created employee with Id : {}", employee.getEmployeeId());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/createEmployees", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> createEmployees(@RequestBody List<Employee> employeeList) {
        int count = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            employee.setEmployeeId(random.nextInt(999999));
            employeeRepository.save(employee);
            log.info("Created employee with Id : {}", employee.getEmployeeId());
            count++;
        }
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("countOfObjectCreated", String.valueOf(count));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).headers(responseHeaders).build();
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/updateEmployee/{employeeId}", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> updateCustomer(@PathVariable("employeeId") int employeeId, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        Optional<Employee> optionalDbEmployee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeId(employeeId);
        if (optionalDbEmployee.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Employee dbEmployee = optionalDbEmployee.get();
        dbEmployee.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
        dbEmployee.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
        dbEmployee.setExtension(employee.getExtension());
        dbEmployee.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
        dbEmployee.setOfficeCode(employee.getOfficeCode());
        dbEmployee.setReportsTo(employee.getReportsTo());
        dbEmployee.setJobTitle(employee.getJobTitle());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteEmployee/{employeeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("employeeId") int employeeId) {
        employeeRepository.deleteById(employeeId);
        log.info("Employee with employee id {} Deleted successfully.", employeeId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    String lastName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "EXTENSION")
    String extension;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    String email;

    @Column(name = "OFFICE_CODE")
    int officeCode;

    @Column(name = "REPORTS_TO")
    Integer reportsTo;

    @Column(name = "JOB_TITLE")
    String jobTitle;
}
```

**OfficeResource.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/office")
@Slf4j
public class OfficeResource {

    @Autowired
    OfficeRepository officeRepository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/greetOffice", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Office !!!";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/getAllOffices", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<Office>> getAllOffices() {
        List<Office> officeList = officeRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(officeList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/getOffice/{officeCode}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Office> getOffice(@PathVariable("officeCode") int officeCode) {
        Optional<Office> optionalOffice = officeRepository.findByOfficeCode(officeCode);
        if (optionalOffice.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(optionalOffice.get(), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/createOffice", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createOffice(@RequestBody Office office) {
        Random random = new Random();
        office.setOfficeCode(random.nextInt(999));
        officeRepository.save(office);
        log.info("Created office with office code : {}", office.getOfficeCode());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/createOffices", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> createOffices(@RequestBody List<Office> officeList) {
        int count = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Office office : officeList) {
            office.setOfficeCode(random.nextInt(999));
            officeRepository.save(office);
            log.info("Created office with office code : {}", office.getOfficeCode());
            count++;
        }
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("countOfObjectCreated", String.valueOf(count));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).headers(responseHeaders).build();
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/updateOffice/{officeCode}", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> updateOffice(@PathVariable("officeCode") int officeCode, @RequestBody Office office) {
        Optional<Office> optionalDbOffice = officeRepository.findByOfficeCode(officeCode);
        if (optionalDbOffice.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Office dbOffice = optionalDbOffice.get();
        dbOffice.setCity(office.getCity());
        dbOffice.setPhone(office.getPhone());
        dbOffice.setAddressLine1(office.getAddressLine1());
        dbOffice.setAddressLine2(office.getAddressLine2());
        dbOffice.setState(office.getState());
        dbOffice.setCountry(office.getCountry());
        dbOffice.setPostalCode(office.getPostalCode());
        dbOffice.setTerritory(office.getTerritory());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteOffice/{officeCode}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteOffice(@PathVariable("officeCode") int officeCode) {
        officeRepository.deleteById(officeCode);
        log.info("Office with office code {} Deleted successfully.", officeCode);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Office.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFICE")
public class Office {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_CODE")
    int officeCode;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    String city;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    String phone;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE1")
    String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE2")
    String addressLine2;

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    String state;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    String country;

    @Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
    String postalCode;

    @Column(name = "TERRITORY")
    String territory;
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username = ?")
                    .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/employee/createEmployee", "/employee/createEmployees", "/employee/updateEmployee/**", "/employee/deleteEmployee/**").hasRole("Admin")
                    .antMatchers("/office/createOffice", "/office/createOffices", "/office/updateOffice/**", "/office/deleteOffice/**").hasRole("Admin")
                    .antMatchers("/employee/getEmployee/**", "/employee/getAllEmployees").hasAnyRole("Admin","User")
                    .antMatchers("/office/getOffice/**", "/office/getAllOffices").hasAnyRole("Admin","User")
                    .and().formLogin();
    
        }
```

[image: User Details]

[image: Authority details]

After hitting the url "http://localhost:8085/employee/getEmployee/1002" from browser i am getting login form and after enter the credentials for "User1" who is "Admin" user and am getting "Forbidden, status=403" error.

**Need Help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasRole` and `hasAnyRole` prefix your strings with `ROLE_`. Use `hasAuthoritiy` or `hasAnyAuthority` instead. See [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#hasAnyRole(java.lang.String...))

Comment: After making the changes, I am able to access any endpoints which requires either "Admin" or "User" authority successfully with both "User1" and "User2".


But while accessing any endpoints which requires only "Admin" authority with "User1" which is configured to have "Admin" authority; i am getting "Forbidden, status=403" error.